# What does the `use <ClassName>;` syntax mean in the class body in PHP?

Tags: php

In the PHPUnit documentation, I came across some PHP syntax I'm not familiar with.

https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/7.3/database.html#asserting-the-result-of-a-query

```
<?php
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use PHPUnit\DbUnit\TestCaseTrait;

class ComplexQueryTest extends TestCase
{
    use TestCaseTrait;

    public function testComplexQuery()
    {
        $queryTable = $this->getConnection()->createQueryTable(
            'myComplexQuery', 'SELECT complexQuery...'
        );
        $expectedTable = $this->createFlatXmlDataSet("complexQueryAssertion.xml")
                              ->getTable("myComplexQuery");
        $this->assertTablesEqual($expectedTable, $queryTable);
    }
}
```

The `use TestCaseTrait;` is the line I don't understand. I know the `use` delcaration at the top allows the class to be used by name without the full namespace, but I don't know what it's doing here. Searching for `use` in PHP yeilds results about that functionality.

Comment: Read about [PHP traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php).

Answer (score 1):

Easy explain (not the main thing but for an example):
Its for variables and methods which you have to write again and again. With no complex logic!

Trait:

```
trait Name {
    protected $name;

    getName() {
         return $this->name;
    }

    setName($name) {
         $this->name = $name;
    }
}

class test {
    use Name;

    /* In background it looks like that (without comment ;) */
    //protected $name;

    //getName() {
    //     return $this->name;
    //}

    //setName($name) {
    //     $this->name = $name;
    //}
}
```

10 Other classes where you need these variable and methods, you can use them.

And in this testCases you need most of the time the same methods and thats why they just include them like that.

Answer (score 0):

Leave it to the comments on php.net to clarify. The following comment lead me to the term "trait" for this functionality. (I should have guessed by the well-named type.) https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php#119919

To quote the manual:

> As of PHP 5.4.0, PHP implements a method of code reuse called Traits.
>
> Traits are a mechanism for code reuse in single inheritance languages
>   such as PHP. A Trait is intended to reduce some limitations of single
>   inheritance by enabling a developer to reuse sets of methods freely in
>   several independent classes living in different class hierarchies. The
>   semantics of the combination of Traits and classes is defined in a way
>   which reduces complexity, and avoids the typical problems associated
>   with multiple inheritance and Mixins.
>
> A Trait is similar to a class, but only intended to group
>   functionality in a fine-grained and consistent way. It is not possible
>   to instantiate a Trait on its own. It is an addition to traditional
>   inheritance and enables horizontal composition of behavior; that is,
>   the application of class members without requiring inheritance.
>
> https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php

I've never heard of this feature, interesting.